# RMStore: Cancel restore downloads

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, rmstore

I'm using RMStore to manage in-app purchases and I'm hosting content on iTunes Connect. It's working great until I try to restore. How do I restore 1 specific download - I can only seem to restore everything and that's a lot of content to download. Alternatively, if there is a way to cancel, can I cancel the remaining downloads once I complete the one I want most?

Comment: As far as I know the restore only download the receipt with the purchases  associated to the apple id provided, What kind of issue are you experimenting?

Comment: With hosted content it starts downloading content for all previously purchased items on restore. So I call restore and it starts download 100mb of data. I'd like to just get the hosted content for a specific product ID.